# Coffeescript, exporting classes only have super functions

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Given

```
class Super:

    constructor: (@params) ->
    foo: ->
        ...

class Child extends Super:

    internalFoo = ->
        ...

    internalBar : ->
        ...


(exports ? this).Super = Super
(exports ? this).Child = Child
```

I know this example would "pollute" the global namespace but for the sake of simplicity: I'm only able to call `foo()` on `Child`

```
var c = new Child();
c.foo(); // works
c.internalFoo(); // internalFoo is undefined
c.internalBar(); // internalBar is undefined
```

What I'm missing here? I would like to run my coffeescripted code in a browser.

Comment: Where do you run this? since your second piece of code is JavaScript (and you use `exports ? this`), I'd guess it's the browser, right?

Comment: Joachim Sauer - Yes. I've added this information to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can call **internalBar** without any problem.

**internalFoo** can't be called as you don't define it as a member function of the class nor as class function. defining it via **"="** will make it only available as a variable to close over within the class body.

If you want to make it a class method define it as

```
 class Child extends Super
     @internalFoo: ->
```

As for not being able to call **internalBar** I would assume you have an indentation error and your **internalBar** is defined as anon function within **internalFoo**. 
which as said before isn't available as you haven't defined it as member method.

Comment: robkuz - thanks for this. +1 for the adivce for making functions class functions.